# Breadth-first search for clusters of pixels in a given color range

Tags: optimization, c, image, clustering, breadth-first-search

I am a beginner in programming languages, so I apologise if my code is badly formatted or doesn't make any sense.

My program gets an image and a RGB color range as input and it counts how many pixels are in each group. A group only contains pixels connected directly, not diagonally, so for each pixel, it searches for valid pixels (in the RGB range) in all 4 directions, and if it finds one it adds it to a queue.

My code has the output I want, but I need it to be about 10% faster. Do you have any ideas of improvements I could make?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "bmp_header.h"
typedef struct
{
unsigned char B;
unsigned char G;
unsigned char R;
} Pixel;
int main()
{
int i,j,k;
int *vpLoc; //Array of location of the valid pixels
int Rr,Gr,Br,Ro,Go,Bo,Rv,Gv,Bv;
int count;
float P;  
int *queue=0;//I will use this for my breadth-first search algorithm
int temp[4]={0};

FILE *input=fopen("input.txt", "rt");
fscanf(input,"%d %d %d %d %d %d %f",&Rr,&Gr,&Br,&Ro,&Go,&Bo,&P);

FILE *in=fopen("input.bmp","rb");
if(in==NULL)
{
    printf("\nCannot open file\n");
exit(1);
}

struct bmp_fileheader Header;
struct bmp_infoheader InfoHeader;

fread(&Header, sizeof(Header), 1, in);
fread(&InfoHeader, sizeof(InfoHeader), 1, in);

Pixel *pArray;
pArray=(Pixel*)calloc(InfoHeader.height*InfoHeader.width,sizeof(Pixel*));

//Read the pixel's info
int nrvp=0; //This will be the number of valid pixels
vpLoc=(int*)calloc(InfoHeader.height*InfoHeader.width,sizeof(int));
for(i=0;i<abs(InfoHeader.height)*abs(InfoHeader.width);i++)
{   
    fread(&pArray[i],sizeof(Pixel),1,in);
Rv=pArray[i].R;
Gv=pArray[i].G;
Bv=pArray[i].B;
//Check if the pixel is valid. If it is, add it's location to vpLoc
if(Rr-Ro<=Rv&&Rr+Ro>=Rv&&Gr-Go<=Gv&&Gr+Go>=Gv&&Br-Bo<=Bv&&Br+Bo>=Bv)
        vpLoc[nrvp++]=i; 


}
fclose(in); 
free(pArray);
//To count the clusters, I will use a breadth-first search algorithm(which I am proud of)   
queue=(int*)calloc(nrvp,sizeof(int));
int carry;  
int buffer=0;
int tmp;
int keeper=0; //This will help reduce the range of for functions
int OK=1;
int cluster[100];//Here I will write the number of pixels in each cluster

for(i=0;i<nrvp;i++)
{   
    if(vpLoc[i]!=0)
    {   carry=i;
    keeper=0;
        OK=1;
        count=0;
    tmp=1;
    k=1;

        while(OK==1)
        {           
            //Check for a valid pixel below
    if(vpLoc[i]>InfoHeader.width)
    for(j=i;j>=0;j--)       
    if(vpLoc[i]-InfoHeader.width==vpLoc[j]) 
    {   
        //If it's index in vpLoc is not already in queue, add it to queue
        for(k=keeper;k<count;k++)
            if(queue[k]==j)
                tmp=0;
        if(tmp==1)  
            queue[count++]=j;
        tmp=1;  
    break;
    }       
            //Check for a valid pixel to the left
    if(vpLoc[i]+1==vpLoc[i+1])
        {
        for(k=keeper;k<count;k++)
            if(queue[k]==i+1)
                tmp=0;
        if(tmp==1)
            queue[count++]=i+1;
        tmp=1;
        }               
            //Check for a valid pixel to the right
    if(vpLoc[i]-1==vpLoc[i-1])
        {
        for(k=keeper;k<count;k++)
            if(queue[k]==i-1)
                tmp=0;
        if(tmp==1)
            queue[count++]=i-1;
    tmp=1;  
        } 
    //Check for a valid pixel above
    for(j=i;j<i+InfoHeader.width;j++)       
    if(vpLoc[i]+InfoHeader.width==vpLoc[j])  
    {
        for(k=keeper;k<count;k++)
            if(queue[k]==j)
                tmp=0;
        if(tmp==1)  
            queue[count++]=j;
        tmp=1;  
    break;
    }
    //Chech for numbers other than zero in queue    
            for(j=keeper;j<=count;j++)
        {
            if(queue[j]!=0)
            {   keeper=j;
        vpLoc[i]=0;
        //Move to the next pixel in queue(if there is one)
        i=queue[j];         
        queue[j]=0;
                OK=1;
                break;
        }                   
    }
    //If the queue is empty, leave the while function
    if(keeper!=j)
            {
        OK=0;
        vpLoc[i]=0;
        count++;
            if(count>=P*InfoHeader.height*InfoHeader.width)
                cluster[buffer++]=count;
                //Reset the cluster count
                count=0;
                i=carry;
    }                       
        }           
    }
}
//Bubble sort is faster for small strings
for(i=0;i<buffer;i++)
{
    for(j=i+1;j<buffer;j++)
{
        if(cluster[i]>cluster[j])
    {
        temp[0]=cluster[i];
        cluster[i]=cluster[j];
        cluster[j]=temp[0];
        }
    }
}
//Now for the output...
FILE *output=fopen("output.txt", "wt");
for(i=0;i<buffer;i++)
    fprintf(output,"%d ", cluster[i]);

fclose(output);
free(vpLoc);
free(queue);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just some generic remarks as I don't have the time at the moment to look at the performance:

1. You said that you are a beginner and apologize for your bad formatting. However there is no real excuse to write badly formatted code. Not sure what editor or IDE you use but if you use something else but notepad most editors and especially IDEs support auto-indenting and can re-format your code. Make use of it. It significantly increases readability which has a direct connection to how easy it is to spot bugs.

   Good formatting means: Proper indenting and to have spaces between operators and things like commas and semicolons. For example this:

   > ```
   > for(i=0;i<abs(InfoHeader.height)*abs(InfoHeader.width);i++)
   > ```

   will read better when formatted like this:

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < abs(InfoHeader.height) * abs(InfoHeader.width); i++)
   ```
2. You don't need to cast the return value of `calloc` in C. In fact it's considered bad practice as it can hide problems (like forgotten to include the appropriate header).
3. You should check the return value of `calloc` - in case it fails it will be `NULL` and you are usually left with a somewhat meaningless segfault when trying to access the memory.
4. You do `calloc(InfoHeader.height*InfoHeader.width,sizeof(int))` but then immediately after in your for loop you do

   > ```
   > for(i=0;i<abs(InfoHeader.height)*abs(InfoHeader.width);i++)
   > ```

   Why do you use `abs` in the for loop? If you think that one of them could be negative then you are already in trouble with `calloc`.
5. You only check the return value of the second `fopen` and not the first one - you should check both. You should also close the first file descriptor if the second `fopen` fails. Even though the open file descriptor will be closed when the process exits it's still a lot nicer to do it properly.
6. Unless I missed it you close `in` but never `input`.
7. Your comparison for valid pixel is duplicating code and could use refactoring into a single method like this:

   ```
   int ColorInRange(int r, int o, int value)
   {
       return r - o <= value && r + o >= value;
   }
   ```

   Not sure what the `r` and `o` stand for but they should be given proper names reflecting their meaning.
8. When you read the bitmap you allocate an array to hold each pixel. Yet you only read one pixel at a time and you also only need it to determine whether or not to add it to `vploc`. This is a waste of memory You only need to have a single `Pixel` structure to store the temporary data in (and you should check the return value of `fread`):

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < abs(InfoHeader.height) * abs(InfoHeader.width); i++)
   {   
       Pixel p;
       if (fread(&p, sizeof(p), 1, in) < 1)
       {
           // read failed
           fprintf(stderr, "Bitmap read error at position %d\n", i);
           exit(1);
       }

       //Check if the pixel is valid. If it is, add it's location to vpLoc
       if (ColorInRange(Rr, Ro, p.R) && ColorInRange(Gr, Go, p.G) && ColorInRange(Br, Bo, Bv))
       {
           vpLoc[nrvp++] = i; 
       }
   }
   ```

   If you want to make it faster instead you could try reading the entire file into memory in one go and then calculate the `vpLoc`. Something along these lines:

   ```
   int nrvp = 0; //This will be the number of valid pixels
   int totalPixels = InfoHeader.height * InfoHeader.width;
   vpLoc = calloc(totalPixels, sizeof(int));
   if (fread(pArray, sizeof(Pixel), totalPixels, in) < totalPixels)
   {
       puts("Failed to read entire bitmap");
       exit(1);
   }

   for (i = 0; i < totalPixels; i++)
   {   
       Rv = pArray[i].R;
       Gv = pArray[i].G;
       Bv = pArray[i].B;
       //Check if the pixel is valid. If it is, add it's location to vpLoc
       if (Rr - Ro <= Rv && Rr + Ro >= Rv && Gr - Go <= Gv && Gr + Go  >= Gv && Br - Bo <= Bv && Br + Bo >= Bv)
           vpLoc[nrvp++]=i; 
   }
   ```
9. You should in general try to find better names for variables - `vpLoc` and and `nrvp` are not very descriptive.
10. You should check the return value of `fopen` before writing the output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your tips are really interesting and I tried each one of them. 4.I use abs in my "for" loop because for some reason it speeds up my program by .5 seconds. 5.I need my code to be faster, that's why I don't check if fopen fails, I also deleted that first check  6.Closing files speeds up my program by .2 seconds. I was really excited to try your 7th point, but it actually made my program a bit slower. 8 saves up memory, but it won't speed up my program.

Comment: @greenro: Yes No. 7 will make your program slower because it introduces additional functions calls. If you make the refactored method static like `static int ColorInRange(int r, int o, int value)` then the compiler will probably inline it and then there should be no notable difference. For number 8: See my updated answer

Comment: I just tried your second idea and it is .4 seconds slower. Also, the reading is pretty fast and also is the forming of vpLoc. They take up to .006 seconds both. The problem seems to be my BFS algorithm, which, depending on the picture, can take up to 2minutes. Do you have any ideas on that part of the code?

Comment: @greenro: I haven't looked into the performance in detail but one operation you seem to be doing **a lot** is to iterate over the queue to find if a certain pixel is already in there. Given that you use the index of `vpLoc` you could try to create a bitset of that size and simply set/check the state of the corresponding bit to track whether it's already in the queue. This should be reasonably easy to implement and not consume too much memory

Answer (score 2):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Format your code consistently

It doesn't matter as much what style you use as it matters that you have a consistent style.  With the varying different indentation levels, it makes it really difficult to understand the underlying structure. The lack of whitespace adds to the difficulty in reading this, so as a result, I actually ran this code through the [`indent`](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) program before I reviewed it.

### Decompose your program into functions

All of the logic here is in `main` in one rather long and dense chunk of code.  It would be better to decompose this into separate functions.

### Check return values of standard functions

Many standard functions, including `fopen`, `fread`, `fscanf` and `calloc` can fail and return values that can help in detecting those failures.  To write robust software, you should get into the habit of checking the return values and dealing intelligently with the potential failures.

### Casts are not needed for `calloc`

The advantage to `malloc` and `calloc` returning a `void *` is that no explicit cast is needed and it may be safely omitted.

### Read all at once instead of pixel at a time

In the first `for` loop, the program reads one `Pixel` at a time within the loop, but this is quite inefficient.  It would be faster to read the entire array at once outside the loop and then proceed.

### Move loop invariants outside the loop

The first loop includes this rather long line:

```
if (Rr - Ro <= Rv && Rr + Ro >= Rv && Gr - Go <= Gv && Gr + Go >= Gv
&& Br - Bo <= Bv && Br + Bo >= Bv)
```

However, most of those variables don't change within the loop.  Your compiler *might* be smart enough to sort this out for you, but you can give it a big hint by precalculating the differences.  In other words, calculate `Rr - Ro` and compare to that.  Also, it doesn't really make much sense to declare three more variables, `Rv`, `Gv` and `Bv` since they are simply aliases for the components of `pArray[i]`.

### Prefer `malloc` to `calloc` where practical

The standard `malloc` call simply allocates memory while `calloc` additionally sets it to contain all zeroes.  Because that takes extra time, only use `calloc` if you actually need that extra step, and in the case of allocating space for `pArray`, you don't need it since all of the memory is overwritten anyway.

### Use pointers rather than indexing for speed

When you need to increase the speed of a program, preferring pointers to indexing is one common way to do that.  For example, the existing code uses `vploc[i]` and `vploc[j]` a number of times, but it could instead use pointers.  For example, instead of this:

```
for (i = 0; i < nrvp; i++) {
    if (vpLoc[i] != 0) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

you could instead write that code like this:

```
const int *vpLocEnd = vpLoc + nrvp;
for (int *loc = vpLoc; loc != vpLocEnd; ++vpLoc) {
    if (*loc) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

This will likely save a lot of time.  If you also need `i` you can do it like this:

```
for (int *loc = vpLoc; i < nvrp; ++i, ++vpLoc) {
    if (*loc) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

### Shortcut loops where practical

Several places in the existing code have constructs like this:

```
for (k = keeper; k < count; k++)
    if (queue[k] == j)
        tmp = 0;
if (tmp == 1)
    queue[count++] = j;
tmp = 1;
```

However, if once `tmp` is set to `0` there really isn't much point in continuing the loop, so a better way to write it would be this:

```
for (k = keeper; tmp && k < count; k++)
    if (queue[k] == j)
        tmp = 0;
if (tmp == 1)
    queue[count++] = j;
tmp = 1;
```

That will save time.  Even better would be to eliminate the variable `tmp`:

```
for (k = keeper; queue[k] == j && k < count; k++)
    continue;
if (k == count)
    queue[count++] = j;
```

### Eliminate spurious variables

As shown above, judicious recoding can eliminate spurious variables.  Next on the list should probably be `carry` which is little used.  I suspect `OK` could also be eliminated with better structuring of the code and a little more thought.

### Avoid changing loop variable deep inside a large `for`

Changing the loop variable `i` within the second large `for` loop is not necessarily a bad thing by itself, but changing it deep inside such a large loop of code is almost certainly going to make the code a little more fragile and harder to understand.  For both those reasons, it's usually best to avoid fiddling with the loop variable(s) within the loop if it can be practically avoided.

### Omit `return 0` at the end of `main`

The compiler will automatically generate a `return 0;` at the end of `main` so it is not necessary to supply your own.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your interest in making my code faster. I have tried all of your suggestions and kept them if they made an even small difference.

What made my code 50% faster was @ChrisWue 's idea. It took me 5 minutes to implement it and it looks like this:

```
char *hStr;
hStr=malloc(nrvp*sizeof(char));
```

And in for checking if the pixel is already in queue, I used my hStr like this:

```
if(hStr[j]==0)
            {hStr[j]=1;
            queue[count++]=j;
            }
```